# SQL Query to filter record for particular record count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which have Identity, RecordId, Type, Reading And IsDeleted columns. Identity is primary key that is auto increment, RecordId is integer that can have duplicate values, Type is a type of reading that can be either 'one' or 'average', Reading is integer that contains any integer value, and IsDeleted is bit that can be 0 or 1 i.e. false or true. 
Now, I want the query that contains all the records of table in such a manner that if COUNT(Id) for each RecordId is greater than 2 then display all the records of that RecordId.

If COUNT(Id) == 2 for that specific RecordId and Reading value of both i.e. 'one' or 'average' type of the records are same then display only average record.

If COUNT(Id) ==1 then display only that record.

For example :

```
Id          RecordId          Type          Reading       IsDeleted 
1           1                 one             4              0
2           1                 one             5              0
3           1                 one             6              0
4           1                 average         5              0
5           2                 one             1              0
6           2                 one             3              0
7           2                 average         2              0
8           3                 one             2              0
9           3                 average         2              0
10          4                 one             5              0
11          4                 average         6              0
12          5                 one             7              0
```

Ans result can be

```
Id          RecordId          Type          Reading       IsDeleted 
1           1                 one             4              0
2           1                 one             5              0
3           1                 one             6              0
4           1                 average         5              0
5           2                 one             1              0
6           2                 one             3              0
7           2                 average         2              0
9           3                 average         2              0
10          4                 one             5              0
11          4                 average         6              0
12          5                 one             7              0
```

In short I want to skip the 'one' type reading which have an average reading with same value and its count for 'one' type reading not more than one.

Comment: people are marking this down but not prepared to comment as to why (very annoying) - the question isn't too clear but there are many worse - Have you attempted to write a query yet? Can you show us your attempt please?

Comment: many worse that received upvote of 8 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with a as
(
select Id,RecordId,Type,Reading,IsDeleted, count(*) over (partition by RecordId, Reading) cnt, 
row_number() over (partition by RecordId, Reading order by Type, RecordId) rn
from table
)
select Id,RecordId,Type,Reading,IsDeleted
from a where cnt <> 2 or rn = 1
```

Comment: @DevendraGohil - if this _did the work_ then why is the record id=2 in your original post but not returned by this answer?! Is your original post wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this program

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,RecordId INT,[Type] VARCHAR(10),Reading INT,IsDeleted BIT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,'one',4,0),(1,'one',5,0),(1,'one',6,0),(1,'average',5,0),(2,'one',1,0),(2,'one',3,0),
(2,'average',2,0),(3,'one',2,0),(3,'average',2,0),(4,'one',5,0),(4,'average',6,0),(5,'one',7,0),
(6,'average',6,0),(6,'average',6,0),(7,'one',6,0),(7,'one',6,0)
--SELECT * FROM @t

;WITH GetAllRecordsCount AS                              
(   
    SELECT *,Cnt = COUNT(RecordId) OVER(PARTITION BY RecordId ORDER BY RecordId)
    FROM @t
)
-- Condition 1 : When COUNT(RecordId) for each RecordId is greater than 2 
 --               then display all the records of that RecordId. 
, GetRecordsWithCountMoreThan2 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM GetAllRecordsCount WHERE Cnt > 2
)
-- Get all records where count = 2
, GetRecordsWithCountEquals2 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM GetAllRecordsCount WHERE Cnt = 2
)
-- Condition 3 : When COUNT(RecordId) == 1 then display only that record.
, GetRecordsWithCountEquals1 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM GetAllRecordsCount WHERE Cnt = 1
)

-- Condition 1: When COUNT(RecordId) > 2
SELECT * FROM GetRecordsWithCountMoreThan2  UNION ALL

-- Condition 2 : When  COUNT(RecordId) == 2 for that specific RecordId and Reading value of 
--               both i.e. 'one' or 'average' type of the records are same then display only 
--               average record. 
SELECT t1.* FROM GetRecordsWithCountEquals2 t1
JOIN (Select RecordId From GetRecordsWithCountEquals2 Where [Type] = ('one') )X
ON t1.RecordId = X.RecordId
AND t1.Type = 'average'     UNION ALL   

-- Condition 2: When COUNT(RecordId) = 1
SELECT * FROM GetRecordsWithCountEquals1
```

**Result**

```
ID  RecordId    Type    Reading IsDeleted   Cnt
1   1            one    4             0     4
2   1            one    5             0     4
3   1            one    6             0     4
4   1            average5             0     4
5   2            one    1             0     3
6   2            one    3             0     3
7   2            average2             0     3
9   3            average2             0     2
11  4            average6             0     2
12  5            one    7             0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is named `the_table`, let's do this:

```
select main.*
from the_table as main
inner join (
  select recordId, count(Id) as num, count(distinct Reading) as reading_num
  from the_table
  group by recordId
) as counter on counter.recordId=main.recordId
where num=1 or num>2 or reading_num=2 or main.type='average';
```

Untested, but it should be some variant of that.

**EDIT** [TEST HERE ON FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cadae/17)

The short summary is that we want to join the table with an aggregated version of o=itself, then filter it based in the count criteria you mentioned (num=1, then show it; num=2, show just average record if reading numbers are the same otherwise show both; num>2, show all records).

Comment: Thank you. But here it is not necessary that average for all records must be exists. I want that if a record with type 'one' is only individual record and its record Id is exists in type 'average' record then discard the 'one' type of record.

Comment: Keep in mind that my addition of `main.type='average'` will only be triggered for records with `num=2`, since `num=1 or num>2` will cover the other bases. The where clause could be rewritten as `(num=1 or num>2 or (num=2 and main.type='average'))` but doing so would be redundant, and therefore unnecessary, so I left it off.

Comment: seems to work : [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cadae/2) ...actually Id 10 has been excluded aswell

Comment: Based on his criteria, it definitely seems like it should be excluded. Ids 10 and 11 both have RecordId=4, so 11 should be showed with because it has the type 'average'.

Comment: @chops ... can I add the fiddle to your post?

Comment: Look, records with Ids 10 and 11 has same record Id but the readings of both have different values, so that both are exits in resultant table.

Comment: @whytheq, Yeah, that's totally fine.

Comment: @devindra, I see, I didn't notice the "reading" requirement.  So if there are two records, and reading isn't the same, then show both records. These requirements are oddly arbitrary. We can add an additional check in the subquery for reading then. No problem. Edit incoming.

Comment: Query updated to check for reading requirements. fiddle updated as well.